# How to properly implement composition in Scala for booking a car with insurance object?

Tags: scala, object

How to implement composition in scala correctly? Do you create the new object in the constructor or body?

Cant really find anything about composition in scala. How to you apply it?

Example:
I am trying to create an insurance object when you are booking a car with the bookCar(), but I dont know how to go about it

```
class bookCar (val customer: Customer, val car: Car) {

}

class Insurance (val customer: Customer) {
  // implement insurance class
}
```

Is it

1

```
class bookCar (val customer: Customer, val car: Car, var insurance: Insurance) {
    insurance = new Insurance (customer)
}

class Insurance (val customer: Customer) {
  // implement insurance class
```

or this

```
class bookCar (val customer: Customer, val car: Car) {
    val insurance = new Insurance (customer)
}

class Insurance (val customer: Customer) {
  // implement insurance class
```

is there a better practice? or are both wrong

Comment: 2nd variant is simpler to use. Keep it simple (KISS-principe). And btw, classes should be declared with UpperCamelCase, and you can skip `val` in constructor params. But actually you probably can combine both ways with `class BookCar(customer: Customer, car: Car, insurance: Insurance = new Insurance(car)) `, despite I still prefer 2nd variant

Comment: i see, thanks. so i never need to all val to my constructors? only var if i want it to be mutable?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: Have you tried either of the two options you've shared here? If not, please try one of them first to see if they work.

Answer (score 0):

Either examples are implementation of composition. If what you mean by composition is "has-a" relationship.
So in both examples you provided, `BookCar` "has-an" insurance. `BookCar`, also has a `Customer` and a `Car`.

Without more information about the problem that the code is trying to solve. The second approach seems to be more correct.

In the first example we are creating a class with a `var` in the constructor that we overwrite right away provides no benefit, and tbh is confusing.

The second example tells a better story. We want to create a car booking, a car booking requires a customer and a car. Once a car booking is created, we assign it an insurance policy automatically.

```scala
class BookCar(customer: Customer, car: Car) {
  val insurance = new Insurance(customer)
}

class Insurance(customer: Customer) { ??? }
```

Another note `BookCar` sounds more like a function name rather than a class name. Maybe `CarBooking` or `Booking` might be more appropriate?

Comment: I think `has-a` is oversimplification for composition, but it satisfies the purposes of this discussion.